# Hardhat: When I deploying a contract to sepolia test-network, I meet the error:"Invalid URL protocol: the URL must start with `http:` or `https:`"

Tags: node.js, ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, hardhat

I code in my `hardhat.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  solidity: "0.8.24",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: "https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/y4r3BgNFU-zhHGd8BWs-OhCMRR7ghpA2",
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 11155111,
    },
  }
};
```

And I run `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia` in the terminal,but there's an error says `Invalid URL protocol: the URL must start with "http:"or "https:"`
Then I direct to where throw out the error, and print out the `url`

```
if (!/^https?:/.test(url.origin || url.protocol)) {
    console.log(url)
    throw new InvalidArgumentError('Invalid URL protocol: the URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.')
  }
```

This is the `url` printed out

```
URL {
  href: 'socks5://192.168.64.1:10808',
  origin: 'null',
  protocol: 'socks5:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: '192.168.64.1:10808',
  hostname: '192.168.64.1',
  port: '10808',
  pathname: '',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: ''
}
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is here:

```
defaultNetwork: "hardhat"
```

it should be `sepolia`.

```
defaultNetwork: "sepolia"
```

also, make sure you import this:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
```